# Co-op in Rayman Legends on PS4

Tags: ps4, rayman-legends

How do i start playing with other people on Rayman Legends for PS4? I haven't found an option in the main menu where you can select your level.

Also, is it possible to play co-op via share play?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How do i start playing with other people on Rayman Legends for PS4?

To start playing co-op you need to:

- [create a second user](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5214/~/user-profiles-on-ps4) in the PS4 settings.
- Start up the game as the original player who has already been logged in.
- On the second controller, press the PSN button and select a user.

This will automaticly add another Rayman inside the game, making the game co-op.

- Note: The second player doesn't require PSN plus to  join the game.